# Functions in Javascript module cannot be recognized for Cordova Android App

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, phonegap

We have a cordova project that there are some functions in the javascript module, when I call those functions, it returns error that the function name is not defined. This only happened in Android app, when I return code in web browser and IOS app. It is working fine.

For html

```
<script type="module" src="xxxReceiver.js"></script>
```

For module js xxxReceiver.js

```
import Receiver from './scriptD/Receiver.js';
var oReceiver = new Receiver();
function receiver_init(){
    oReceiver.init();
}
window.receiver_init = receiver_init;
function receiver_addController(){
    return oReceiver.addController({name: window.xxControllerName,ip_addr: window.xxIPAddress});
}
window.receiver_addController = receiver_addController;
```

For the applied general.js

```
var result = receiver_addController();
```

When try to run the code at general.js for Android Cordova App, it throw error : receiver_addController is not defined.

Understand that Cordova may not support js module, is there any way to solve it?

Comment: webViews do not support newer revisions of JS. You should target ES5 for webviews.

Comment: @Eric, thanks for your advise. The point is the provided library must use import module. I also keep doing research on this, for new version webView, it uses Chrome so it will support ES6. Is it possible for Cordova as well?

Comment: The point is, imports are not supported

Answer (score 0):

After lots of research, a temporary solution for this case is to install plugin "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview", then the app can run ES6 module functions.